# How to insert the dynamically created text box values to db in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, database

my name is fairooj and am a new to php and jquery. i have a problem. i want your help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
$(function(){
$('p#add_field').click(function(){
count += 1;
$('#container').append(
'<strong>Link #' + count + '</strong><br />' 
+ '<input id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '" type="text" />'
+ '<input id="code_' + count + '" name="code[]' + '" type="text" /><br />' );

});
});
</script>
```

this is my script to add more text boxes..

and this is my code for insert it to database

```
<?php
//If form was submitted
if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {

//create instance of database class
$db = new mysqldb();
$db->select_db();

//Insert static values into users table
$sql_user = sprintf("INSERT INTO users (Username, Password) VALUES ('%s','%s')",
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']),
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) );  
$result_user = $db->query($sql_user);


//Check if user has actually added additional fields to prevent a php error
if ($_POST['fields']) {

//get last inserted userid
$inserted_user_id = $db->last_insert_id();

//Loop through added fields
foreach ( $_POST['fields'] as $key=>$value ) {

//Insert into websites table
$sql_website = sprintf("INSERT INTO websites (Website_URL, web_Link) VALUES ('%s', '%s')",
      mysql_real_escape_string($value), mysql_real_escape_string($value) );  
$result_website = $db->query($sql_website);
$inserted_website_id = $db->last_insert_id();


//Insert into users_websites_link table
$sql_users_website = sprintf("INSERT INTO users_websites_link (UserID, WebsiteID) VALUES ('%s','%s')",
      mysql_real_escape_string($inserted_user_id),
  mysql_real_escape_string($inserted_website_id) );  
$result_users_website = $db->query($sql_users_website);

}

} else {

?>
```

**the problem web_Link sql table is repeating Website_URL table value....

please how can i solve this

am waiting for your reply..**

Comment: Print the post first and see inside `if ($_POST['fields']) { 
var_dump($_POST);` and see what that prints. Add that result here and let us see that so we can help you further.

Comment: Website_URL, web_Link both having should same value? what should

Comment: web_link value is code?

Comment: yes code is text box id for web_link

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are looking this?

```
$code=$_POST['code'];
$fields=$_POST['fields'];

mysql_real_escape_string($value), mysql_real_escape_string($code[$key]) );
```

Detail

```
$countKey=0; // add this Line

//foreach ($_POST['fields']) {
for($i=0;$i<count($fields);$i++){

   $result_website = $db->query("INSERT INTO websites (Website_URL, web_Link) VALUES ('".$fields[$countKey]."', '".$code[$countKey]."')");  

  $countKey=$countKey+1; // add this Line
}
```

Comment: this is k but this code is inserting last values only

Comment: yes. like this                                                      if ($_POST['fields']) {  var_dump($_POST);
  
  
  //get last inserted userid
  $inserted_user_id = $db->last_insert_id();
  
  //Loop through added fields
  foreach ( $_POST['fields'] as $key=>$value )
  $code=$_POST['code']; {
   
   
   //Insert into websites table
   $sql_website = sprintf("INSERT INTO websites (Website_URL, web_Link) VALUES ('%s', '%s')",
              mysql_real_escape_string($value), mysql_real_escape_string($code[$key]) );  
   $result_website = $db->query($sql_website);

Comment: no this is inserting 1st web site last web_link and last website first web_link only...

Comment: then you do this: $fields=$_POST['fields']; mysql_real_escape_string($fields[$countKey]), mysql_real_escape_string($code[$countKey])

Comment: no its also inserting the first texbox group datas only... i added a image wid u what i want. i edited this pic in photoshop... [link](http://www.4shared.com/download/Ko7Iunekba/Untitled-2.jpg?lgfp=3000)

Comment: please help me am doing a project and am struggle in this area. sorry to disturb u....

Comment: i have attache a image link with u actually what i want. [link](http://www.4shared.com/download/Ko7Iunekba/Untitled-2.jpg?lgfp=3000)

Comment: Previuos and present one, looks same!

Comment: Whats the output you are receiving and exactly what o/p u want?

Comment: [link](http://www.4shared.com/download/usmxapbLba/Untitled-3.jpg?lgfp=3000) this is what i want

Comment: this is the error [link](http://www.4shared.com/download/6RXOnRvOce/Untitled-4.jpg?lgfp=3000)

Comment: k am thnkz again. k bye

Answer (score 0):

if i have two array to insert into database then i have one way of counting array size example is given below

```
$arry1=array("abc","def");
$arry2=array("efg","hij");
$count=sizeof($arry1);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
     echo $sql="INSERT INTO tablename (`col1`,`col2`) VALUES (".$arr1[$i].",".$arry2[$i].")";
}
```

Comment: i don't want to count. and am a new to php. do you have any sample code for dynamic creating text boxes and insert values to db?